# Facebook changes my URL variable values when scraping it?

Tags: facebook, url, web-scraping, canonical-link

OK, here is a weird one...

Try putting this URL (http://dev.bride.ca/wedding-dresses/index.cfm?page=1&shopRegions=162&GownTypeID=1&maxGownPrice=1000&GownLabelID=12) through the Facebook debugger.

Here, just click this : http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.bride.ca%2Fwedding-dresses%2Findex.cfm%3Fpage%3D1%26shopRegions%3D162%26GownTypeID%3D1%26maxGownPrice%3D1000%26GownLabelID%3D12

See the weird change?

When it creates a canonical URL which to parse, it takes the very last URL variable (*GownLabelID=**12***) and changes it to "*GownLabelID=**0***"

Actually, it does the same with the previous variable : *maxGownPrice=1000* becomes *maxGownPrice=**0***

But it does not do it with all the variables, just those two. And it does not do it to the last two. I swapped the order and moved the last one to the beginning and it still did it to the same variable.

I am out of ideas.. ANYONE??

Thanks in advance! (*) this being on the DEV server, feel free to try different things etc. It is not "live" to consumers or anything..

Answer (score 1):

> When it crates a canonical URL which to parse, it takes the very last URL variable (GownLabelID=12) and changes it to "GownLabelID=0"

The scraper does not “create” the canonical URL – it reads them from your page’s OG meta tags.

*You* are the one that put

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://dev.bride.ca/wedding-dresses/index.cfm?
page=1&shopRegions=162&GownTypeID=1&maxGownPrice=0&GownLabelID=0"/>
```

into the page’s HTML code – and the scraper just follows what you’re telling it.

Comment: OMG, you are right!! Hahahaha
I think it has to do with session variables. When I view source, it says ID=92 - but when FB comes by (new session) it defaults to zero.